# How to make NVDA read alert correctly?

Tags: html, wai-aria, nvda

When I trash an item, a new page is loaded and an alert is rendered like so:

```
@if (Model.SuccessMessage != null)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("somePath/SuccessAlert", @Model);
}
```

SuccessAlert:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <span class="float-left glyphicons glyphicons-ok"></span>
            <div class="ml-5">
                <h4 class="alert-heading">Delete successfull</h4>
                <p class="mb-0">Find the item for 30 days in trash.</p>
                <a href="someUrl">Recover</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want NVDA to read heading, text and link on load. But the heading is somehow omitted and the link is read 3 times. The output of NVDA is:

"alert
Find the item for 30 days in trash. 
Recover.
Recover.
Recover. link visited"

I also just discovered that it depends on the browser:

- Chrome: NVDA output like above is triggered. The alert is missing in the source code, though I find it with the dev tools.
- Firefox/IE: NVDA output for the alert is not
  triggered. The alert is present in the source code.

In all browsers the alert is reachable with NVDA. This is just about the triggered output on load.

**Edit:** This seems to be a pure NVDA issue, see: https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/11068

Comment: how are you building that alert and how are you inserting it into the DOM? You should be building it and then appending it, if you are appending items to the DOM one by one it will cause strange behaviour. Also are you inserting the whole element or does it already exist on the page?

Comment: also (not related to your problem) the hyperlink should be replaced with a button if it does not cause navigation to occur (and if it does cause navigation the url should be in the hyperlink.)